# What's the POSIX-compliant way to get the epoch timestamp in a shell?

Tags: shell-script, date, posix, timestamps, time

I just noticed, that POSIX [`date`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) doesn't seem to have the `%s` or `%N` format items. So I can't use those. What's an alternative, yet POSIX-compliant way to get the epoch timestamp in my shell script?

Comment: I'm not sure what a Posix-compatible `stat` command is supposed to print, but you might be able to touch a temporary file, and get its mtime as seconds-since-the-epoch.

Comment: On a GNU system you can use `touch tmpfile; stat --format=%Y tmpfile`. On a BSD system you can use `touch tmpfile; stat -f %Um tmpfile`.  (I grant that neither of these is POSIX.)

Comment: @SteveSummit, it isn't supposed to print anything, since there's no such command listed in the specification... (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/idx/is.html). On a GNU or BSD system they could just use `date +%s`. Probably in a lot of others too.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, well, there's a reason I'm entering these ideas as comments, not answers. :-)  Writing a small C program, as in the first half of your answer, is IMO clearly the right way to go.  (Me, I don't even have to; I've got five or six tools in my personal toolbox that will do it. :-) )

Answer (score 31):

For the epoch time as an integer number of seconds, that would be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand(); print srand()}'
```

or:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print srand(srand())}'
```

As [in POSIX `awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_12), `srand()` without argument uses the current time to seed the pseudo-random generator. It also returns the previous seed, so the second `srand()` above returns the epoch time that was used for the previous one¹.

You can get the fractional part with something like:

```
echo|LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0 diff -u /dev/null - |sed -n '2s/.*\(\.[0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

[POSIX does specify the output format for `diff -u`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html#tag_20_34_10_07), and that the current time be used when the file is `-`.

But several thousands if not millions of nanoseconds will likely have elapsed since you called `awk` earlier before you get the output, it may not even be the same second. You may however be able to check if it's the case by comparing `<epochtime> % 60` with the *second* part of the (UTC) timestamp in the `diff` header if you were so inclined.

---

<sup>¹ About that `awk` solution, note that POSIX used not to say it in so many words. I did [raise an objection](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=983) to POSIX some time ago about the unclear wording, also stating that it was unreasonable in this day and age to force implementations to use that poor a source of entropy. Instead the [resolution](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=983#c3371) was to explicitly require `srand()` use the epoch time.</sup>

Comment: well, I didn't expect this :D

Comment: @ilkkachu see also https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=983#c3281 for an even more convoluted alternative.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas On the one hand, this is certainly an... imaginative solution.  But on the other hand, and I hope you don't mind my saying this, it is *absolutely hideous!* Me, I'd never use it; it's just way too obvious that (despite tortured discussions such as you referenced) it might not work everywhere, or forever.

Comment: I love this answer, and it's really clever, but I don't think it's correct. [POSIX specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) for awk's srand: "Set the seed value for rand to expr or use the time of day if expr is omitted. The previous seed value shall be returned." But it does not say what form of the "time of day" is "used", and seems to allow for the implementation to chose something like a hash of the epoch timestamp, just the HH:MM:SS part, a timestamp against a different epoch, etc.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE see the footnote.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Oh wow, excellent! It does seem to codify that it's only 32-bit though, making this approach EOL'd.

Comment: Amazing!  But I think I'll just stick with `perl -le 'print time'` even though it's not POSIX.

Answer (score 13):

Write a C program that calls `time()` and prints the result. Borrowing from sample program in [the specification of the `time()` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/time.html), let's call this e.g. `seconds.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t) t);
    return 0;
}
```

and compile with `c99 -o seconds seconds.c`. (If I read the [spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/c99.html) correctly, that should be a standard way to compile it.)

---

Alternatively, you could take the decomposed date and calculate the number of seconds from that. It's relatively easy since all days are 86400 seconds long. We do need to get rid of the leading zeroes from some values so that they're not taken as octal by the shell arithmetic:

As a shell function:

```
epochtime() {
    eval "$(date -u +'y=%Y j=%j h=%H m=%M s=%S')"
    s=${s#0}
    m=${m#0}
    h=${h#0}
    j=${j#0}
    j=${j#0}
    t=$(( ((y-1970)*365 + (y-1969)/4 + j - 1)*86400 + h*3600 + m*60 + s))
    echo "$t"
}
```

Note on the leap year calculation: The first leap year after the epoch is 1972, and (1972-1969)/4 = 3/4 = 0 , while (1973-1969)/4 = 4/4 = 1 (relying on integer truncation). Hence (year-1969)/4 gives the number of leap years *before* the current year. The possible leap day in the current year is included in the `%j` value, the "day of year". That one counts from 1 up, but we want the number of complete days elapsed, hence the minus one in the expression.

Comment: I think the shell function will be inconsistent if the current year is a leap year and you're calling it before 2/29. You add in the extra day in the year before the day actually occurs.

Comment: @doneal24, it should be ok, actually. (y-1969)/4 only gives 1 in 1973, the year _after_ the first leap year after the epoch. Any leap day in the current year comes from `%j`. You can change the first line to e.g. `eval "$(date -d "${1-now}" -u +'y=%Y j=%j h=%H m=%M s=%S')"` and then test e.g. `epochtime '2020-01-01 12:00'`  against `date -u -d '2020-01-01 12:00' +%s`. (With a `date` that has `-d`)

Comment: That makes sense. While the function takes a while to puzzle out, it's still intuitively better than calling `srand()` in `awk`.

Comment: Do you know what will be the output of your function on `01-01-2107` ? Is it correct ?

Comment: @IsaaC, for obvious reasons, it'll be off by a day in 2101 already. I'm fine with that, and if anyone asks in 75 years, I'll be happy to fix it for them (usual force majeure exceptions applying). Other than that, if you have something in mind, you're free to post your findings in a comment. Not necessarily because I'd care, but in case you think someone else might. Better yet, if you think the existing answers on this question are lacking, post an answer of your own with a better solution.

Comment: @IsaaC I'll be dead by then and then it's not my problem anymore.

Comment: @MechMK1 You do not need to be in 2107 to try that date. Try `faketime 2107-01-01 ./script`.

Comment: @done, that hardly matters, as `faketime` isn't a POSIX utility

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with a custom `date` format string that produces a shell arithmetic expression for the POSIX formula for seconds since the epoch:

```
secs=$((`TZ=GMT0 date \
+"((%Y-1600)*365+(%Y-1600)/4-(%Y-1600)/100+(%Y-1600)/400+1%j-1000-135140)\
*86400+(1%H-100)*3600+(1%M-100)*60+(1%S-100)"`))
```

This approach is taken from https://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html

Comment: ok, that's a nice trick for dealing with the leading zeroes.

Comment: @ilkkachu: The original version had a bug there that was fixed by a reader's bug report and suggestion to use the 1 prefix.